# римановое многообразие or риманово многообразие?

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова, прилагательные, possessive-adjective

In mathematics the technical term Riemann manifold (or Riemannian manifold) denotes a type of space investigated by the nineteenth century German mathematician Bernhard Riemann.
The corresponding Russian term is sometimes written *римановое многообразие*: no surprise here. 
However I seem to have more often come across the expression *риманово* (without an *е* at the end) *многообразие*.
Since the genitive of *Pиман* is, I guess, *Pимана* with upper case P, the shorter (and to me stranger) form *риманово* cannnot be a genitive and seems thus also to be an adjective.
What is the explanation for this variant ?

Comment: Риманово многообразие/ риманово пространство/  гилбертово пространство/ евклидово пространство/ пространство Лобачевского

Comment: Thank you for the interesting examples, Elena.

Answer (score 7):

These are so-called [possessive adjectives](http://www.study-languages-online.com/grammar/tables/possessive-adjective-declensions-in) which are used extensively (but not exclusively) in science, medicine and religion:

- булева алгебра
- базедова болезнь
- ахиллесова пята
- прокрустово ложе
- декартово произведение
- сизифов труд

They are formed by adding the suffix -ов (-ев, -ёв) to the motivating stem (usually denoting a person). Russian surnames (Иванов, Петров) have the same structure and follow the same declension pattern, except for the prepositional case: об ивановом - об Иванове.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg in the modern language **-ов** surnames aren't perceived as possessive adjectives and are inflected as nouns instead which is morphologically manifest in Prepositional case and also in Dative **ивановому** (adj) vs **Иванову** (noun), but paradigmatically in all cases in the form of accent shift, Nom. **ивАнов** (adj.) vs **ИванОв** (noun), Gen & Acc. **ивАнова** (adj) vs **ИванОва** (noun), Inst. **ивАновым** (adj) vs **ИванОвым** (noun)

Comment: @ Баян Купи-ка: Yes, but here the name is Риман, not Риманов, so it seems to me that we can only be faced with an adjective.

Comment: @Sergey: but if we have a possessive *adjective*, I don't understand why it is not in the neutral form   риманово**e** многообразие, just as in your example булев**а**  алгебра. Are there adjectives in the neutral gender that end with **-o**?  I thought that **-o** ending was for neutral *nouns*, not adjectives.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg indeed, in the phrase you're asking about it IS possessive adjective, i've only explained the difference Sergey mentioned...  possessive adjectives only have a form which corresponds to the shortened form of standard adjective so while the short neuter form of **хорошее** is **хорошо** there's only one possessive adjective form **риманово**, there's no such adjective as **римановый/-ая/-ое** and it wouldn't make much sense from the semantic perspective as it would have the connotation of ***made of Риман*** or ***having the qualities of  Риман***

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg a good example of the difference can be made with the adjective **урановый** - there's a chemical element **уран** and there's a Greek god **Уран** (whom the element is named after), the adjective **урановый/-ая/-ое** always refers to **уран** the element - **урановый рудник, урановая бомба, урановое стекло** that is ***related to  Uranium*** or ***made of Uranium***, however with reference to **Уран** the god the only correct adjective would be possessive **Уранов** because it's an animate noun describing an individual able to possess things unlike **уран** the element

Comment: Thank you again, Баян Купи-ка.

Answer (score 6):

This is a possessive adjectival form.

> Притяжательные прилагательные - разряд прилагательных, выражающих
>   принадлежность чего-либо лицу или животному (отцовы сапоги, волчья
>   нора). П. п. образуются с помощью суффиксов -ов(-ев), -ин, -ий.

[source](http://russkiyyazik.ru/721/)

The suffix **-ов(-ев)** doesn't seem to be productive any longer so its use is confined to proper names and members of stable collocations which emerged when it was still current. To name a few **базедова болезнь** (after physician Basedow), **прокрустово ложе** (after mythological figure Procrustes), **Эйфелева башня** (after Gustave Eiffel), **бикфордов шнур** (after William Bickford), **бертоллетова соль** (after Сlaude Berthollet), **крокодиловы слёзы** (today we'd say ***крокодильи***).

This is the same form as the one typical Russian surnames are fashioned in (**Иванов ← Иван, Петров ← Пётр, Сидоров ← Сидор**). Originally it was supposed to be followed by the words **сын** or **дочь** and functioned as patronymic before formal surnames appeared → **Марья Иванова дочь**, **Фёдор Петров сын**, much like is the case of many Anglo-Saxon, Scandinavian and other nations' surnames. In Russian it may look unusual in neuter gender, because we're used to it in either masculine or feminine.

It's also employed in the expression **`драть как Cидорову козу`** where **Cидорова** means Sidor's (feminine).

Possessive adjectives answer the question **чей?** (whose?) whereas regular adjectives answer the question **какой?** (what (kind of)? which?)

Comment: I'd like to add that римановое sounds really awkward to me (russian native). About as awkward as "Пифагоровые штаны"...

Comment: As a variation of the possessive, "риманов**ск**ое" is grammatically possible here. The choice depends on tradition (_броуновское_ движение vs броуново, _эйнштейновская_ теория vs эйнштейнова).

Comment: @tum_: I have no idea what you mean by "Пифагоровые штаны", since *штаны* seems to mean *trousers*.  Are you being sarcastic? Anyway that an expression "sounds really awkward  to a Russian native" does not explain to a non-native speaker what he should use.

Comment: `It's also employed in the expression драть как Cидорову козу where Cидорова means` - LOL! "demanding scrupulous adhering to mutually exclusive paragraphs". Here they make "Sidorova" a clear female surname. Because a possessive "Sidor's" would be written with small "c" like all the examples before.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg "пифагоровы штаны во все стороны равны" - that is a humorous saying, albeit I can hardly grasp its sense too. The graphical representations of the theorem might be seen as some quite strange sort of pants form some uber-simplistic cartoons. Guess it helped students to remember this theorem is somehow about triangles and squares

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg "малиноВОЕ варенье" - jam MADE OF raspberry, of parts of raspberry plant; "бульварНОЕ кольцо" - ring/circle consisting of (in a sense, made of) several adjacent/intersecting boulevards in Moscow. "европейское сообщество" - a unity composed by a criterion of belonging to Europe, again in a sense made of parts of Europe. Same way "римановое" многообразие sounds like "made of Riemann" or something built inside Riemann and using Riemann like a containing body (like maybe some dwarves seeing Riemann as a planet and carving their mines inside him)

Comment: Thank you, @Arioch. What you explain is interesting and quite unexpected (even strange!) for a non Russian native.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg also we can remember adjectives like зелёное - green-coloured, like painted by or made of зелень (green plants mass). Малиновое mentioned above can also mean the colour. Малиновое платье obviously is not dress made of rapsberry but one coloured like rapsberry. Same way фиолетовое - violet-coloured. But all in all, with full adjective ending, -OE, we characterize some innate quality of the object. Some inner characteristic, the object itself. However posession is some external relation. If X owns his slave Y that still keeps the, very distinct objects.

Comment: "Riemann manifold" does not equate Riemann and a manifold in total or in part. It keeps them distinct and unaltered. It just draws some external to them relation between them. So, -OE would not fit there. It would blend the manifold and Riemann into one object. It would mean some part or essential attribute is Riemann himself, not just vaguely realated to him. Then "ск" suffix of "римановское" adds this distance another way. Like in "русское", "норвежское", "американское". Transforming "of Riemann's essence" into "of Riemann's kind"

Comment: Now, look back at my earlier example of "европейское сообщество", frankly i had troubles to somehow rationalize that expression, i remember. And the explanation there above is clumsy i think. With this later reflection about "ск" suffix i now see that fault much better :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Римановое` is plain wrong - it turns animate subject into inanimate adjective.

However, `Римановское` exists as a variant of norm, that is of `Риманово`.